# Mac wakes on scheduled power event that recreates itself every day

Tags: sleep-wake, power-management

At 2:14 every morning, my Mac wakes. Looking at the logs, I see it's a scheduled event, but nothing shows up in System Preferences > Power. When I go to terminal, and run pmset -g sched, I see

```
Scheduled power events:
[0]  wake at 03/31/13 02:14:00
```

Only one, for the next event. I can delete it through pmset, and it won't wake that night (morning). The next day, there's a new event. So for instance, after that one went, now I see

```
Scheduled power events:
 [0]  wake at 04/01/13 02:14:00
```

I've locked the Power Management preferences, I've even set the com.apple.AutoWake.plist file to remove all write access through chmod, and the next day... a new entry appears.

Taking Lauri's suggestion, I ran opensnoop on the Autowake.plist, and at 2:15, this happened, inserting that power event:

```
2013 Apr  4 02:15:00     0     20 powerd         4 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.AutoWake.plist 
2013 Apr  4 02:15:00     0     20 powerd         5 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.AutoWake.plist 
2013 Apr  4 02:15:00    89  15241 mdworker       4 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.AutoWake.plist
```

I didn't see anything in /Library/LaunchDaemons/ or /Library/LaunchAgents/ that seemed relevant. Execsnoop returned

```
2013 Apr  4 02:15:00    89  15241  14058 mdworker
2013 Apr  5 02:15:00    89  24165  19851 mdworker
```

What the heck is going on, and how do I stop this from happening? Or what's the next step to troubleshoot this? Thanks.

Vitals: it's a Mac Mini, 10.8.3, but it's done this for ages (including when migrated from a previous Mac Mini via Time Machine).

Comment: Have you checked everything in /Library/LaunchDaemons/ or /Library/LaunchAgents/? You could try running `sudo opensnoop -v -f /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.AutoWake.plist` and `sudo execsnoop -v > exec` in two shells. Or just run `sudo crontab -e` and add something like `*/10 * * * * pmset repeat cancel`.

Comment: Done, and watching the file offered some new information, thanks.

Comment: powerd is what modifies the file when you use pmset. The execsnoop command redirects output to a file named `exec`, which might show what other processes start before powerd.

Comment: Thanks. Done, and added the excerpt from the output. There's nothing around the 02:15 entries that seems consistent (a lot of coreservicesd, mdworker, but not at the same timestamps every night...)

Answer (score 2):

Run syslog |grep -i "Wake reason" from the terminal.

Reference this article: http://osxdaily.com/2010/07/17/why-mac-wakes-from-sleep/

**Update**: `log show | grep -i "Wake reason"`

Comment: Done -- all I see are normal wake-on-keyboard events, like

`$ syslog | grep -i "Wake reason"`
`Mar 30 14:12:45 Dereks-Mac-mini kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?`
`Mar 31 10:59:36 Dereks-Mac-mini kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?`

Comment: What USB devices do you have plugged in?  For me, my unexplained wake up was caused by a usb mouse.  Once I unplugged it, no more issues.

Comment: Keyboard, mouse. I also would expect if it's USB that it'd show in the wake reason -- was that true for you?

Comment: Yes, it did show in the console log.  It ended up being my Razer Orochi mouse.

Comment: Right, but did it show as Wake Reason = USB, or what I'm seeing, as Wake Reason: ?. I'm skeptical this is the cause since a USB device might wake it, but is unlikely to be creating a scheduled power event every night for 02:14.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this issue while trying to resolve out mine. I realize the OP is YEARS old, but the problem persists.

From what I've gathered, it appears to be related to Weekly Usage reports.

This was what I put together and resolved with (source article listed below):

- I was having the same problem as you described
- I discovered a scheduled wake call for 10pm nightly, in **System Information > Power** (would find my battery drained over night)
- Neither `pmset -g log | grep "Wake Requests"` or `pmset -g sched` produced any results visible results for me
- I finally traced down my issue here:
  `cat /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.AutoWake.plist`
- Was able to resolve (hopefully) using this:
  `sudo pmset schedule cancelall`
- WakeEvent no longer shows in Sys Info > Power

Another user in the following article (last post) said this was his solution:
`sudo pmset -b tcpkeepalive 0`

After some research, I found the Apple Discussion [**com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report keeps waking my Macbook Pro at night while lid closed**](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253541761).  I pulled my solution from it.

Answer (score 0):

The article posted here may help you. It details some plist files to delete that will be recreated on the next power up.

http://tancredi.co.uk/2007/12/9/solving-macbook-wake-from-sleep-issue

Comment: Thanks. I'll report back and edit this when results are in. Initially, there was no reference to a 02:14 wake event in either file, and after deleting and recreating, the 02:14 event still doesn't show in Power Scheduling/these files, but appears when I do pmset -g sched.

Comment: This seems to not have helped: the scheduled power event is still being inserted somehow.

Answer (score 0):

On 2013 era macs, the System management controller (SMC) keeps it’s own clock and schedule so [you may want to reset that](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245223/how-am-i-supposed-to-know-if-smc-reset-has-taken-place) and then check again in system preferences to see if the wake schedule is being set there.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

I have not seen this failure mode on the T2 and [Apple Silicon era Mac hardware](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406873/is-there-an-equivalent-to-resetting-nvram-on-an-m1-mac) but a one time SMC reset followed by a one time NVRAM reset would usually do the trick on a sticky reboot setting.