# Is there an equivalent to resetting NVRAM on an M1 mac?

Tags: macos, mac, nvram, apple-silicon

I have an M1 Mac Mini that is exhibiting some strange issues that aren't going away after reinstalling macOS. I'd like to reset its NVRAM or whatever the nearest equivalent is for M1 macs, in case something there is causing persistent problems.

Are there equivalent steps to Intel Macs with T2 chips to reset things when the symptoms are not specific?

Comment: What is one strange issue? I would be happy to update my no answer based on of there are things to address something specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no SMC or NVRAM reset on the new hardware. Same as on iOS, iPadOS, watchOS, tvOS and HomePod hardware.

- https://eclecticlight.co/2020/11/28/startup-modes-for-m1-macs/
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Yes, you can run a `nvram` command and read/write to a key-value store, but the reset at boot key command is gone.

I would open a support case for each specific item that’s strange. We now have detailed logs and a very capable recovery infrastructure for debugging boot issues so out with the old, embrace the new is my current motto.

Comment: Are you sure there's no NVRAM? In the course of using this system I've already used the nvram terminal command to add additional boot arguments per Apple's instructions for doing DriverKit development.

Comment: Why would Apple say there is no NVRAM reset publicly @GuyGizmo ? Are you on DTK or shipping hardware?

Comment: I'm on shipping hardware. You may be correct that M1 macs don't have NVRAM in precisely the same way that an intel mac does, but there are obviously settings that persist between boots, and they can be edited using the `nvram` terminal command, regardless of whether it's called "NVRAM". So what I'm looking for is the nearest equivalent of resetting NVRAM on an M1 mac -- something that resets these persistent settings to their defaults, to be used in case something has gone wrong. (I'll edit my question to use more general language.)

Comment: We don’t reset the NVRAM on iPhone, iPad, watch, TV or HomePod - why would this have to carry over @GuyGizmo

Comment: Macs are a different beast than those devices. Those also don't let you install other operating systems, software from outside of the app store, or give you low level terminal access that lets you edit NVRAM settings directly. So it makes sense that, as a repair tool, there would be a way to reset NVRAM or its nearest equivalent to fix problems. Of course Apple doesn't have to include it, but I think it's a good idea since it's been helpful for solving problems before.

Comment: @GuyGizmo I’m not trying to argue with you, just explain what I see and know was done. You will find single user mode is gone, verbose mode boot is gone, NVRAM key combinations are gone.

Comment: That's disappointing that Apple removed those options. I've certainly made good use of them over the course of debugging issues on various macs.

Comment: It was a hammer, now we have scalpels for debugging @GuyGizmo

Comment: @bmike it takes a skilled professional years of training to use a scalpel, but anyone can use a hammer.

Comment: @zac and they will with gusto. What’s really fun is seeing skilled professionals use hammers since they are so approachable, the skill sometimes takes close observation to become evident.

Answer (score 3):

Per my conversation with a 3rd tier NVRAM *does* exist on the chip, but it runs a test on startup and "automatically" resets if needed. There is no way to trigger it manually although.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Knowing that it happens automatically admittedly makes me uncomfortable. These days I don't think I trust Apple to decide when nvram should be reset.

Comment: same, but what we can we do...